# What is the origin of the name for the tabletop miniature company "Ral Partha"?

Tags: history-of-gaming, miniatures

It sounds like something out of an old pulp fantasy novel. Is it someone's actual name, or is it just something made up? I read the wikipedia article and there's no mention of where the name came from.

Where did the name "Ral Partha" come from?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

According to a letter from Jack Hesselbrock, a former president of the company, "Ral-Partha" was the name of a wizard character played by John Winkler, a friend of one of the company's founders:

> Ral Partha was a name made up by John Winkler. John is a friend of Tom Meier. John was playing the original D & D in high school. He had a wizard character he named RAL-PARTHA. He came up with this name because he thought it Middle Eastern sounding. RAL-PARTHA was extremely successful and it was hoped some of this success would spill over into the fledgling miniature company. The hyphen was somehow dropped.
>
> - Jack Hesselbrock, President,
>   Ral Partha Enterprises, Inc.

I can't find a definitive original source on the letter (e.g., one published on Ral Partha's website), but it's reproduced [here](http://theminiaturespage.com/man/ralparthastory.html) and described again [here](http://www.stunties.com/stunties/index.php?title=Ral_Partha_History).  This story is also corroborated by an interview with John Winkler himself, found in the October 1982 issue of [Cincinnati magazine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cincinnati_(magazine)) and accessible online in brief preview form [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=VR4DAAAAMBAJ&pg=PA22&lpg=PA22&dq=%22ral%20partha%22%20%22john%20winkler%22&source=bl&ots=bf7F4xxhtk&sig=fZJIHe_BPbjt89xoasY0Q-Nd1vI&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjChPbxj43aAhXrdN8KHT2ACQcQ6AEIQjAI#v=onepage&q=%22ral%20partha%22%20%22john%20winkler%22&f=false).